# Select value based on computation of column value and aggregate

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to build a Grafana Dashboard to understand what SQL queries are processed by my PostgreSQL server. I'm using the [`pg_stats_statements` extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgstatstatements.html).

This is the query I currently have:

```sql
SELECT
  query,
  calls,
FROM pg_stat_statements 
ORDER BY calls DESC limit 3;
```

Which gets me these results:

```
query    | calls  
---------+--------
 Query 1 | 500000 
 Query 2 | 250000 
 Query 3 | 250000
```

Now, I'd like to select an additional value, in addition to `calls`, to see the share of each `calls` value compared to `sum(calls)` on all rows. This is the expected output:

```
query    | calls  | share
---------+--------+------ # 1 000 000 total calls
 Query 1 | 500000 | 0.5   # 500 000 / 1 000 000
 Query 2 | 250000 | 0.25  # 250 000 / 1 000 000
 Query 3 | 250000 | 0.25  # 250 000 / 1 000 000
```

Is it possible to do that and if yes, how can I rewrite my query to get this output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH sum_query AS MATERIALIZED
(select sum(calls) as call_sum from pg_stat_statements)
select 
    ps.query, 
    sum(ps.calls), 
    avg(round((ps.total_time/ps.calls)::numeric,2)) as mean_time,
    sum(ps.calls) / (select call_sum from sum_query) as "share"
from pg_stat_statements ps
group by ps.query
```

In this query, I use `WITH AS MATERIALIZED` for performance.